# Function similar to require.context for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, require

I'm doing something like that:

```
let context = require.context('raw!./', true, /\.js$/);
console.log(context(context.keys()[0]));
```

So as you can see, I'm getting array of file's names and later I'm printing file content.
Also, I did follow "dirty" guide, how to have something like require.context on node.js:
https://github.com/halt-hammerzeit/webpack-isomorphic-tools/issues/48

Well, all works perfect, until I'm calling:

```
console.log(context(context.keys()[0]));
```

Of course I'm getting

> TypeError: context is not a function

My function:

```
function requireContext(base, scan_subdirectories, regular_expression) {
    const contents = {};
    function read_directory(pattern_)
    { }
    read_directory(base);
    return {
        keys: () => { return Object.keys(contents)},
        constructor: function requireContext(data) { return data}

    }
}
module.exports = requireContext;
```

Is there any way to call it like webpack version?
Or I'm just dumb and missed something?

Comment: The problem is that you're returning a plain object, instead of a function. The field `constructor` bears no particular function. The correct approach is to assign a `keys` property to a function and return that function. However, your code as is is ill-defined, so I can't make out exactly how the correct version will look.

Comment: well, how about using glob.sync? This function don't have to be exactly like webpack version, but in this case we have error while running it on node.js :D well, I'll do like you said, thansk :D